# Array in javascript returning as 'null'

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm using HTML and javascript to make simple web games to play.
so giving preset value as an "map element" by using arrays and library.

calling values in an array goes like this:

```
array = [a,b,c,d]
   blah.innerHTML = array[1] // returns "b"
```

or

```
lib = {a:"cat",b:"dog",c:[a,b,c,d]}
   blah.innerHTML = lib.c.1(or lib.c[1])  // returns "b"
```

shouldn't it?

well it returns as an error by saying something like "the null value is null" (i had to translate it)

it used to work for sure, but it doesn't anymore... might know why?

used Software: ie8(im in some kind of "closed society"), dreamweaver

Comment: should be `lib.c[1]` , also is it `['a','b','c','d']` or `[a,b,c,d]` ?

Answer (score 3):

If `a,b,c,d` are `strings`, you should `quote` them:

```
lib = {a:"cat",b:"dog",c:['a','b','c','d']}
```

You need to surround the values in single or double quotes because they are `string` values.

Answer (score 1):

You array should be:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d']
lib = {a:"cat",b:"dog",c:['a','b','c','d']}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Array_literals

Answer (score 0):

In first snippet `array` is javascript [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
array = [a,b,c,d]
   blah.innerHTML = array[1] // returns "b"
```

SO `array[1]` will return the element at index 1.

In this snippet `lib` is an [**Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) & `c` is a key of `lib`

```
lib = {a:"cat",
       b:"dog",
       c:['a','b','c','d']}
  var _c = lib.c // will give ['a','b','c','d']
var blah = document.getElementById("blow") // id of a DOM element
blah.innerHTML = _c[1]  // returns "b"
```

NOTE:`a`,`b`,`c`,`d` in `[a,b,c,d]` will try to refer some variable. Unless declared it will throw error

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ndemh7s3/)